# a subclass calling the method of it's superclass(which is also a subclass)

Tags: java, inheritance, subclassing

i've search this site, and others for a few hours to no avail. Currently, I'm working with inheritence and have hit a bump in the road. I have a super class called Plant, which has subclasses called Vegetable, and Flower. and a subclass called Tomato which extends the Vegetable class, now my problem is that my Tomato class cannot access methods of any classes above it.

So basically I am asking, if C extends B, and B extends A, why is C not syntactically able to accessing public methods from A or B in my program?

```
public class Tomato extends Vegetable{

private String breed;

public Tomato(String o, int s, String b)
{
    super();
    breed = b;
}

public String getBreed()
{
    return breed;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "[Owner: " + getOwner() + " , Sprouts: " + getSprouts() 
            + " , Breed: " + getBreed() + "]";
}

public void water()
{
    if(breed.toLowerCase().contains("porterhouse"))
    {
        int numSprouts = getSprouts();
        setSprouts(numSprouts*3);
    }
} }
```

I receive errors on the method call getOwner() and getSprouts(), only the accessor methods. getOwner() is a public method in the plant class and getSprout() is a method in the Vegetable class, which is class directly above it in the hierarchy.

Comment: tomatoes are actually fruit ;)

Comment: @MartinS, True. C cannot *directly* call any methods from A using `super`, but B could pass function calls up to A.

Comment: Show us some code. `C` should be able to call public methods from `A` and `B`.

Comment: More code. What errors do you receive? *Be specific.* This is gazing into the crystal ball.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood it correctly : **Tomato** can access public methods of **Vegetable** and **Plant**.

```
public class Plant {
    public void getPlant(){
         System.out.println("In Plant");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tomato tomato = new Tomato();
        tomato.getTomato();

    }
}


class Vegetable extends Plant{
    public void getVegetable(){
        System.out.println("In Vegetable");
    }

}

class Flower extends Plant{
    public void getFlower(){
        System.out.println("In Flower");
        getPlant();
    }
}

class Tomato extends Vegetable{
    public void getTomato(){
        System.out.println("In Tomato");
        getVegetable();
        getPlant();

    }
}
```

Output:

In Tomato

In Vegetable

In Plant

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to describe is a multilevel inheritance. [Here](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/multilevel-inheritance-in-java-with-example/) is an example of it. Yes, sub class can access any method of it's parents as long as they are public/protected.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a "bridge" between classess:

```
class A {
    public String getA() {
        return "A";
    }
}

class B extends A {

    @Override
    public String getA(){
        return super.getA(); //uses getA from A class
    }
}

class C extends B {
    @Override
    public String getA(){
        return super.getA();  //uses getA from B class
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    A a = new C();
    System.out.println(a.getA());
}
```

Prints: A

Comment: Uhm...in that case just don't override `getA()` in `B` or `C`...this does not solve anything.